# Javascript OOP - how the object call its instance method?

Tags: javascript, oop

I wrote my first Javascript with OOP. And I am trying to call its instance method from another method within same object.

When I call begin() method like below which is fired after closing the dialog, I get `"this.after() is not a function".`

If other language like Java, it should just process without any problem. 
Is there anything I'm missing?

I am using jQuery bind() for dialog close event so "this" must be pointing to not class itself.

```
function MyHandler() {

    this.begin = function() {
            $("#hiddenIframe").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                height: 300,
                width: 300
            });


            $("#hiddenIframe").bind("dialogclose", function() {
                this.after();
            });
    }

    this.after = function() {
        //do something here
    }
}

var myInstance = new MyHandler();
myInstance.begin(); //error: this.after() is not function ???
```

Comment: [JavaScript's `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is radically different to Java's, but still your code example should work. What happens if you call `myInstance.after();` instead of `myInstance.begin();`?

Comment: I'm sorry the example above works. (I simplified code a bit so it must have been the changes I made) I will edit the code.

Comment: I don't get this error. Is there more context? What version of JavaScript engine are you using?

Comment: Sorry guys I have modified the code and now it really show the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function MyHandler() {

    var thisInstance = this;

    this.begin = function() {
        $("#hiddenIframe").bind("dialogclose", function() {
             thisInstance.after();
        });
    }

    this.after = function() {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

Thank you, Juicy Scripter. I don't know how jquery `dialog` calls `dialogclose` event handlers, but the described error indicates that context of the call of anonymous function with `this.after();` inside it is not `MyHandler`, and `this` means something else there. To be explicit about whose method `after` is, define local variable in `MyHandler` constructor and use this variable when you need to call `MyHandler` instance methods inside functions that will be called in unknown context.

Comment: Your code is correct, but is good to add an explanation why it works. Not only solve problems, help others to understand and learn why it happens and how to deal with similar problems in future

Comment: Note that *this* is not “context” (at least not in the sense that ECMA-262 uses that term), it is a key word (essentially a local variable) that is set to a particular value depending on the function call. In non–strict mode, it is always an object—either the object that the function is called as a method of, a new object inside a constructor called with *new*, an object supplied by *call* or *apply*, or if none of the above, the global object. In the case of a listener called by an event handler, it is set to the element whose handler called the function.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery binded functions executed in context to what they binded.

You have `#hiddenIframe` as `this` in your event listener

You probably want to store pointer to your instance in some variable and use it later in contexts other than instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any problem in you code. It works !!
There is also another simple way of representing the same Object i.e. in the form of JSON.

See the code below:

```
<script>
     var MyHandler= {
                begin:function() {
                    console.log('inside begin');
                    after();
                },
                after:function() {
                    alert('inside after');
                }
      };
     var myInstance = MyHandler;
     myInstance.begin();
</script>
```

Dialog Box code with OOP java script function:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function MyHandler() {
    this.begin = function() {       
            $("#info").show().dialog("open");
            $("#info").bind("dialogclose", function() {
                this.after();
            });             
    }
    this.after = function() {
            $("#info").dialog("destroy");
    }
}
function showDialog(){
    var myInstance = new MyHandler();
    myInstance.begin(); 
}
$(document).ready(function() {
   var info=$("#info");
   info.dialog({
           autoOpen: false,      
           height: 300,
           width: 300,
           title:'Hello Dialog',
           autoClose:false,
           closeOnEscape: true

       });
    $("a").click(showDialog);   
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="showDialog()">Show the Dialog</a>
<div id="info" style="display:none;font-size:10px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You modified code provided by OP so it completely different from original, that's why it works

Comment: SOrry Umesh, my original had no error (cuz i simplified it). Plz refer to current code.

Comment: Oh, this changes everything, sorry.

Comment: ok mastaro-san, If you have not got, Please, See the above improved code below I posted.

Comment: Sorry, don't see how the initial question became so complex in your answer, when it was just a simple scoping issue on `this`.